# Bootstrap 4 - Navbar title on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on a site using the new Bootstrap 4 for a group that unfortunately has a long name and as a result, I am having issues with displayed this name in the navbar. As shown in the picture below, the long name has caused the burger button (the 3 line thing) that opens up the nav options has dropped down to a second line. Due to complicated issues relating to Scrollspy I need to prevent this to ensure that the navbar is the same height regardless of device screen size. Is there a way I could either prevent this from happening or set mobiles to have a different shorter title text, such as "Webpage Name", which would allow the name to fit beside the burger button. I know this was possible in Bootstrap 3, however, I cannot find a working alternative in Bootstrap 4.

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" id="main-nav-bar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png" class="navbar-sqnlogo d-inline-block align-top">Annoying Long Webpage Name</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#about" id="aboutlink">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#whatwedo">What We Do</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#join">Join</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found for Bootstrap v4-beta:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" id="main-nav-bar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="navbar-sqnlogo d-inline-block align-top">
        Long <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Web Page </span>Name
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" href="#about" id="aboutlink">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" href="#whatwedo">What We Do</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" href="#join">Join</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav
```

For reference, the classes `d-*-*` do this.